# pass authentication header to image requests in iframe

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I am sure that title of my question doesn't makes much sense, but i couldn't think better now.

Problem: My main task is to show **all pages** of a SSRS report in a popup inside one of the pages of a ASP.NET MVC application.

To achieve this I used below approach:

1. Add a jQuery popup in MyPage.cshtml(i need report contents inside this popup)
2. When this popup opens(on some client action), I make a jquery ajax request to second page proxyPage.aspx
3. On proxy page I make a webrequest to reportserver with network credentials and get report html

   ```
       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( "http://MyReportServer/ReportServer?/ MyReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format =HTML4.0&rc:Toolbar=false&Param1=blabla123");
       request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MYUSERNAME, MYPASSWORD);
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
       StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
       string str = readStream.ReadToEnd();
       Response.Write(str);
   ```
4. HTML from proxyPage I write in a div inside popup or using iframe to show full proxy page inside it.
5. Till here things go well and thereafter I get yet another problem for which I am writing this question
6. When report's HTML gets rendered in popup it makes request to report server to retrieve images embedded in report.

Since these requests to report server doesn't send network credentials as I did in step 3, I get prompt for entering credentials.

I need a approach through which these image request may somehow get authenticated by credentials that I have already supplied earlier.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS will stream the resources in a location you specify.

```
private byte[] InternalRenderReport(Report report, List<ReportParameter> parameters, string format, int pageNumber, ref int totalPages, string virtualTempFolder, string physicalTempFolder)
        {
            CheckConnection();
            byte[] result = null;
            ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService _execService=new ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService();


            sys = _systemService.GetCurrentSystem();
            _execService.Url = sys.ReportingServices.ServiceRootURL+"/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(sys.ReportingServices.Credentials.UserName, 
                                                                 sys.ReportingServices.Credentials.Password,
                                                                 sys.ReportingServices.Credentials.Domain);
            _execService.Credentials=credentials;

            ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue[] rsParams = null;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                rsParams = new ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue[parameters.Count];
                int x = 0;
                foreach (ReportParameter p in parameters)
                {
                    rsParams[x] = new ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue();
                    rsParams[x].Name = p.ParameterName;
                    rsParams[x].Value = p.SelectedValue;
                    x++;
                }
            }
            StringBuilder devInfo = new StringBuilder();
            if (format.ToUpper().StartsWith("HTML"))
            {
                devInfo.Append("<DeviceInfo>");
                devInfo.Append("<HTMLFragment>True</HTMLFragment>");
                devInfo.Append("<Section>" + pageNumber.ToString() +"</Section>");
                devInfo.Append("<StreamRoot>" + virtualTempFolder + "</StreamRoot>");
                /*devInfo.Append("<Zoom>200</Zoom>");*/
                devInfo.Append("</DeviceInfo>");                
            }
            else
                 devInfo.Append("<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>");

            string extension;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string[] streamIDs = null;
            ReportExecution2005.Warning[] warnings = null;




            ReportExecution2005.ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ReportExecution2005.ExecutionHeader();
            ReportExecution2005.ExecutionInfo rpt = _execService.LoadReport(report.ReportPath, null);

            if(rsParams!=null)
                _execService.SetExecutionParameters(rsParams, "en-us");
            _execService.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
            _execService.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID = rpt.ExecutionID;


            //result = _execService.Render2(format, devInfo, ReportExecution2005.PageCountMode.Actual, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, streamIDs);
            result =  _execService.Render(format, devInfo.ToString(), out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            if (format.ToUpper().StartsWith("HTML"))
            {


                // For each image stream returned by the call to render,
                // render the stream and save it to the application root
                string FilePath = physicalTempFolder;
                byte[] image;
                // For each image stream returned by the call to render,
                // render the stream and save it to the application root
                foreach (string streamID in streamIDs)
                {
                    image = _execService.RenderStream("HTML4.0", streamID, null, out encoding, out mimeType);

                    FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(FilePath + streamID);
                    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);                    
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }

            rpt = _execService.GetExecutionInfo();
            totalPages = rpt.NumPages;

            return result;
        }
```

This will return either raw HTML or the contents to push a file. I added a Temp folder to the solution to be deployed to the server. you can place a web.config file in the temp folder with the following contents to allow extension less contents as ssrs will render when using streams:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>

      <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="image/png" />


    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <clear />

      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then use the following to functions to get the physical and Virtual Temp folders:

```
PhyscicalTempFolder= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\";
VirtualTempFolder=return  Url.Content("~/Temp/");
```

And finally to clean up after each day you can add a powershell command similar to:

```
Remove-Item D:\xxx\WebApplications\ExternalReports\Temp\* -exclude *.config
```

Then add a .bat that calls the PS script:

```
powershell -command "& 'C:\xxx\Scripts\SSRSCleanTempFiles\SSRSCleanTempFiles.ps1'"
```

With this you can configure a scheduled task on the server to call the .bat file everyday and clean the temp folder of your application.